# Magento custom fields

Tags: magento

I have added new custom fields (checkbox) in catalog\category. using Installer.
it appears in a new tab as i want but can't save the value checked,
if anyone can help me to save the custom Checkbox Value.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have added an attribute using the install script, and although Magento will display a checkbox the data won't be saved, even if you are using the eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean source model.

I would consider using a select rather than a checkbox.  However if you require a the input to be a checkbox, you will need to create your own input & source model to handle it.